# python how to get date from a start date + no of days excluding weekends

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

I need python function to get end date with input as startdate and no of days excluding weekends.

For ex Start Date = 01-01-2021 and no of days is 40 how to end end date excluding weekends i.e. calendar days.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`bdate_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html):

```
d = pd.bdate_range('01-01-2021', periods=40)
print (d)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06',
               '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12',
               '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-18',
               '2021-01-19', '2021-01-20', '2021-01-21', '2021-01-22',
               '2021-01-25', '2021-01-26', '2021-01-27', '2021-01-28',
               '2021-01-29', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-02-03',
               '2021-02-04', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-09',
               '2021-02-10', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-12', '2021-02-15',
               '2021-02-16', '2021-02-17', '2021-02-18', '2021-02-19',
               '2021-02-22', '2021-02-23', '2021-02-24', '2021-02-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Comment: Thank you this helps however how can I get the end date rather than the dates. So in above example I just need "2021-02=25"

Comment: @goe - I think simpliest is `d.max()`

Comment: @goe - Or indexing `print (d[-1])`